# How to resolve config from file and also few config programmatically?

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config, hocon

In my use case, I have a scenario where I want to populate some of the configs from the typesafe config file itself and some of those, I want to set programmatically. For example, for below `myconfig.conf` file

```
env=staging
topic=${env}_${event}
```

In above, snippet, `topic` should be resolved as `staging_someevent` event where `someevent` is set in one of the method which resolves this value based on argument in the job using `args`.

I am able to resolve one of those but not both. Below code resolves `${event}`

```java
String event = "someevent";
File file = new File("myconfig.conf");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
String configText = ConfigFactory.parseReader(reader)
  .resolveWith(ConfigFactory.parseString("event=" + event))
  .root
  .render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise().setJson(false));
System.out.println(configText);
```

Similarly, below code resolves `${env}` but how can I resolve both?

```java
String configText = ConfigFactory.parseReader(reader)
  .resolve()
  .root
  .render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise().setJson(false));
System.out.println(configText);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `withFallback` to chain configs together?

Comment: @Tim I tried that but didn't work out for this case. I think `withFallback` just overrides? Not sure though

Comment: @Tim I think you were right. `withFallback` helps. I was able to resolve them by having two configs. When I tried, I didn't call `resolve()` on fallback config which didn't resolve even though it was just straight `key=value` config.
Thank you